# Fourth derivative of $f(x)=e^{4/x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Fourth derivative of $f(x)=e^{4/x}$

I keep trying to calculate this but I can't get it right... Can somebody walk me through this? I get it's just the product rule and chain rule, but dang!! The correct answer is supposed to be:

$$f^{(4)}(x)=\frac{4e^{4/x}(24x^3+144x^2+192x+64)}{x^8}$$

Comment: yup, Is like a huge son between chainrule and product rule. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key rule you need is
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left (\frac{e^{4/x}}{x^n}\right)=\displaystyle - \frac{n  e^{4/x}}{x^{n+1}} - \frac{4  e^{4/x}}{x^{n+2}}.$$
Then very slowly,
\begin{align} &\mathbin{\phantom{=} }\frac{d}{dx}\left (\frac{d}{dx}\left (\frac{d}{dx}\left (\frac{d}{dx}\left (\displaystyle e^{4/x}\right)\right)\right)\right) 
\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left (\frac{d}{dx}\left (\frac{d}{dx}\left (\displaystyle - \frac{4 e^{4/x}}{x^{2}}\right)\right)\right)
\\
&= \frac{d}{dx}\left (\frac{d}{dx}\left (\displaystyle \frac{8 e^{4/x}}{x^{3}} + \frac{16 e^{4/x}}{x^{4}}\right)\right)
\\
&= \frac{d}{dx}\left (\displaystyle - \frac{24 e^{4/x}}{x^{4}} - \frac{96 e^{4/x}}{x^{5}} - \frac{64 e^{4/x}}{x^{6}}\right)
\\
&= \displaystyle \frac{96 e^{4/x}}{x^{5}} + \frac{576 e^{4/x}}{x^{6}} + \frac{768 e^{4/x}}{x^{7}} + \frac{256 e^{4/x}}{x^{8}}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

If you log the function you get the first derivative equal to
$$
h_1(x) = f'(x)=-\frac{4}{x^2}e^{\frac{4}{x}}
$$
The second derivative will be
$$
h_2(x) = \frac{8}{x^3}e^{\frac{4}{x}} -\frac{4}{x^2}f'(x)
$$
And you can use the first derivative. Repeat twice more.